# .NET Library class in vba - multi level domain object

Tags: c#, .net, vba, com, regasm

I'm using .NET Library class in Excel VBA.
It works. I can compile and register it by RegAsm.
Using the Intercaces in .Net and COM attributes like ([InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)])  , generally i see methods and objects
in VBA Intelisence and I can use it

But ... I would like to use a complex multi-level object domain. Get it by some method and i have problem with list of child objects as a property of parent object.

My Method in C#

```
    public object GetParentWithChildList()
    {
        var parent = new Parent
        {
            ParentName = "John",
            Children = new List<object>
            {
                new Child {ChildName = "Tom"},
                new Child {ChildName = "Brian"},
                new Child {ChildName = "Eva"}
            }.ToArray()
        };
        return parent;
    }

    public class Parent
    {
        public string ParentName { get; set; }
        public object[] Children { get; set; }
    }
    public class Child
    {
        public string ChildName { get; set; }
    }
```

object[] , I think  is the best way to return list of objects for VBA/VB6
It works when i have 1 level object. e.g. i would like to return just list of objects. 
object[] wokrs better than Child[] or List

And in VBA it works only partially:

(Main object calls LibDataAccess)

```
Sub GetParentWithChildListVbaTest()
Dim qda As LibDataAccess
Dim parent As parent

Set qda = New QgeDataAccess
Set parent = qda.GetParentWithChildList()

Debug.Print (parent.ParentName)   ' Works OK - it returns John

Dim child As child
Set child = parent.Children(0)     ' This line returns error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment
Debug.Print (parent.Children(0).ChildName)
End Sub
```

My questions are:
How to return an object with a list of subobjects as a property (prepared in .NET for VBA ) ?
Do I have the wrong code in C # or in VBA ?

Comment: COM has no concept of generics. You have to create some sort of wrapper. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474100/access-net-generic-objects-from-vba?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: Yes, You have right. that's why I use object[] Children  not IList<Child> Children. but problem was with reading it under vba

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
 I have solution.
 Code in VBA had mistakes not in C#

instead of this:

```
Dim child As child
Set child = parent.Children(0)  
Debug.Print (parent.Children(0).ChildName)
```

should  be something like this:

```
Dim child As child
children = parent.Children 
Set child = children(0)
Debug.Print (child.ChildName)
```